# Rails - Create a scope based on grandchild property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'm trying to create a scope for a class based on the grandchild status.

I have a class Saga, which has many stories which have many Chapters, and I want Saga to have a scope where only sagas with a chapter in a story is published. Chapter.published is a boolean

```
class Saga < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stories, -> { order(:order) }

  def self.default_scope
  end
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :saga
  has_many :chapters, -> { order(:order) }

  def self.default_scope
    where(saga_id: nil)
    lambda{ where('EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM chapters WHERE chapters.published = 1 AND chapters.story_id = stories.id)') }
  end
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story

  def self.default_scope
    where(published: true)
  end

end
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `.joins()` method of ActiveRecord:

```
class Saga < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :has_published_chapter, -> {
    joins(stories: :chapters).where("chapters.published IS TRUE")
  }
```

Comment: I think this should be `joins(stories: :chapters)` because `Saga` has no knowledge of `chapters` except through `stories` and the where clause could be `where(chapters: {published: true})`

Comment: Tried, and now I have this error:
Association named 'chapters' was not found on Saga; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Replaced with `joins(stories: :chapters)`, and it is working ! Thanks a lot man !

Comment: If you had `has_many :chapters, through: :stories` on the saga.rb model, what I posted originally would have worked...

Comment: As a note `IS TRUE` would be database specific e.g. SQL Server likes `=1` where as `where(chapters: {published: true})` lets the adapter make the determination as to how to assemble the query